# Is it possible to update wavelet packet from fixed-sized window of data without repeating the whole process?

Tags: wavelet, real-time, cwt

Assume that a scalogram is generated from performing wavelet packet in a fixed size window of data. Then, is it possible to update the scalogram with the incoming and outgoing data points without performing the wavelet packet all over again (from scratch)?

If it is possible, how to update the scalogram?

Comment: *Wavelet packets provide a finer resolution for scalogram.* um, quotation needed? This sounds wrong; the time/frequency resolution tradeoff fully applies to them, as for any other integration kernel. The chosen tradeoff might (or might not!) fit the requirements of the application better.

Comment: I have removed it. I don't mean to compare it with other time-frequency distributions.